# Ruby using incorrect OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

We've been running into SSL bad handshake issues. After some debugging and advice from others it was suggested we upgrade our openssl lib. We have done so but Ruby does not seem to recognize the new library is there. See our output below -

```
root@35eb5687d852:/home/app/web# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
built on: Tue May 31 17:07:11 UTC 2016
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/ssl"
root@35eb5687d852:/home/app/web# ruby -r openssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

There is one other stack question about this but it relates to OS X. This is on an Ubuntu 14 machine. Not sure if this was more relevant here or Serverfault but since the issue appears to be in Ruby thought I'd post here.

Is there a way to force Ruby to recognize the new version? Note we are NOT using rbenv or rvm.

Comment: Using an OpenSSL from 2014 is asking for bad times. Upgrade if you can! Ruby uses whatever it was compiled against which may differ from what's actually installed.

Comment: Agreed - another reason we are moving to a new version. We're just testing with 1.0.1g plan to use 1.0.2h. Didn't realize Ruby supports what it was compiled against. We'll attempt to re-compile and see what comes up.

Comment: Ruby sometimes gets compiled against a custom version of OpenSSL to work around platform-specific issues that may crop up. I know RVM is a big fan of doing this. The packager for Ubuntu is responsible for shipping binaries and these may be composed the same way.